# Codeigniter Identify Every 3rd user Registration referral

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently developing an MLM Website using Codeigniter Framework.

And I am working on registration now. I can register successful with referral user

The problem is every 3 registration using my referral username/id i need to run another query because in 1st and 2nd referral I earned 200. and in 3rd user will refer i will only earn 100.

How can I do that in Codeigniter? anyone done this? please help

Comment: Codeigniter has nothing to do with your issue.  Can you not count the number of registration against a referral ID e.g. select count(*) from registrations where referral ID = 'XXXXXX'; and if this count is 2 then you know its the 3rd registration?

Comment: Thank you for answer bro :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me throw some light on this
So lets say you make a post for every registration, the post goes to a class names registration and a register method, and the referral id runs as a session (refID). Also, you have a registration model, this is what you should likely do:

```
class registration extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('registration_model');
    }

    //ensue to check for the existence of the refID session before processing
    function register(){

        if($_POST){
            //first run form validation
            //you should have auto loaded the form_validation library
            //and created a rules function that carries the form rules
            $rules = $this->rules();
            $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                //load view here
            }else{
                //first, get post data
                //then get the number of registration done by user using the refID
                //if registration is greater than 2, set earnings to 100
                //set earnings to 200
                //then proceed to insert registration and do something else



                //get post data, assumed post data
                $name = $this->input->post('name');
                $email = $this->input->post('email');

                //get number of registrations
                $numOfRegs = $this->registration_model->getRegByRefID();

                //set the earnings from the number of registrations
                $earning = $numOfRegs < 3 ? 200 : 100;
                //please note that the for $numOfRegs = 4, $earnings will be 100, as this was not specified in the question

                //at this point, you have set the earnings, you can proceed to do whatever you wish to do, perhaps insert the records

                //please note that this code block just explains what you can likely do after setting the earnings
                $insert = array(
                    "name" => $name,
                    "email" => $email,
                    "earning" => $earning
                );
                $this->registration_model->insert($array);
                // then do anything else
            }
        }else{
            //load view here
        }
    }
}
```

Now this is how your registration model will look like this

```
class Registration_model extends CI_Model{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getRegByRefID(){
        $refID = $this->session->refID;
        return $this->db->get_where('mydb', array("refID" => $refID))->num_rows();
    }


}
```

I hope this explains what you really wants, and helps you. If you find any difficulty, kindly comment and lets sort it out.

Comment: thanks @sunday this really helps me :) this is exactly what i need. thank you again..

Comment: may I ask again for another help? I will post new question

Comment: Okay, post please, I will assist accordingly